# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.6:repackage

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to run a sample maven project. Below is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>  
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    

</project>
```

and I am getting below errors. Tried to find the solution from official documentation of Spring boot maven plugin, not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.835 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-23T09:30:45Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.6:repackage (repackage) on project demo: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.6:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.6:repackage (repackage) on project demo: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.6:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
```

I tried to modified pom.xml file as per Spring Boot Maven Plugin Documentation, but not able to find any soultion yet.

Comment: First you are mixing different spring boot versions `<version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>  ` remove the manual defined version here... Also there should be a class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which I suppose is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.6:repackage failed: Unable to find main class

Please define main class in `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass> <!-- add your actual main class -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```